# How do I turn this into "will" form?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words

I am trying to say "You **will** not feel good if you eat such food" and this has been my attempt so far:

> そんな食べ物を食べれば、君はいい感じない

How can I express "will not" in this case? Also, any corrections in general are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenses generally do not correspond well between English and Japanese.  Japanese-speakers usually just use the present tense to talk about near future events and we could always tell from the context.

Natural-sounding Japanese sentences for "You will not feel good if you eat such food." would be:

> 「そんなもの[食]{た}べてると[元気]{げんき}になれないよ。」
>
> 「そんなのばかり食べてると元気になれないぞ。」
>
> 「そんなの食べてると[身体]{からだ}に[悪]{わる}いぞ。」

As usual, one could not arrive at a natural-sounding phrase if one TRANSLATED from another language.  If you find my English understadable, that is because I am not translating from Japanese.

Comment: I think it would be useful to avoid using ぞ and even unnecessary よ in samples, because topic starters would think this is a normal way to say things.

Comment: @Rilakkuma: That is an interesting suggestion for what  could be a good discussion: I am not sure I agree with you. Things may have changed but when I reflect on when I started Japanese, I feel the teaching of " the normal language as spoken" put too much emphasis on what not to say.  Examples need to reflect what learners will hear. Apart from anything else, it maximises passive learning.

Comment: @Tim: in this particular case "ぞ" is used which is an empathic particle used mostly in masculine gender-specific language. You won't hear it on the every corner and definitely never hear it in an official setting. This means this particular case is quite bit away from "what not to say" cases. This is why beginners are taught politely neutral language - it is virtually context-independent and can be used without doubt in nearly any situation.

Comment: I think this counts as 'translating' just fine; I'd say what you're referring to here is 'literal translating' or 'direct translating', or something like that. At least according to my understanding, anything that carries an equivalent -meaning- is a translation, regardless of how faithfully it represents the -structure-.